# Appcelerator - Open dialpad for ongoing call?

Tags: appcelerator

I need to open the dialpad linked to the ongoing call. Lets say if you call an answering machine and need to "press 2".

I need to emulate this for the user.

I know how to open the normal dialpad for calling, but I need the other one.

Comment: Android? iOS? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, its currently regarding Android, but I also need this for iOS later on.

I have tried to open phone dialer with these:

var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_CALL,
    data: 'tel:1234567'
});
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);

--------------------

Titanium.Platform.openURL('tel:'+phone_number);

Comment: I can already tell you for certain it isn't possible on iOS as there natively is no way to intercept this / make calls from apps. Please edit your question with what you tried, what the result is of what you tried and what you expect to exactly happen